# Migrating a VMware ESXi 3.5 image from one server to another

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, migration

The primary reason we're migrating is to keep all our configuration settings ... php, mysql, Apache Solr ... the same when we change servers. The existing server is behind a firewall and that's all configured properly.

I'm assuming these are the things I'll have to update once the migration is complete:

- IP address
- DNS Domain
- Mail Server MX Records (to point to new mail server if required)

Is there anything else I'm forgetting?

Comment: Your question is way too broad right now.  You haven't mentioned anything about how your esxi hosts/farm(s) operate/interact, etc.  If you can edit it with more detail as to **how** you are going to do the migration, then we'll be able to better assist you on items to update post-migration of the VM.

Comment: By `image` I assume you mean `guest` or `virtual machine`. If so then to answer your questions, in order: 1. Probably. 2. Maybe but not likely. 3. Possibly but not probably. - `Is there anything else I'm forgetting?` How would we know?

Comment: It's a pretty simple question in my view, you have a VM that's hosted on one server. You want to move the vmdk image from that server to a new server. What do you have to reconfigure, assuming a pretty straightforward LAMP setup?